# NoMethodError in Nutritions#new - undefined method '' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have an error in my nifty_scaffold...
For some reason (didn't change any standard code, checked the routes.rb, ...), creating a new nutrition won't work.

Could anyone explain me how and what the solution is?

I think i have included all necessairy code...

The error in detail is:
undefined method `generated_methods' for nil:NilClass

Route contains:

```
map.resources :nutritions
```

View: New

```
<% title "New Nutrition" %>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
<p><%= link_to "Back to List", nutritions_path %></p>
```

View: _form

```
<% form_for @nutrition do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :ammount %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :ammount %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :unit %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :unit %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :kcal %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :kcal %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :protein %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :protein %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :carb %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :carb %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :fat %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :fat %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :class %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :class %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And my nutrition controller

```
  def new
    @nutrition = Nutrition.new
    #raise @progress.inspect (debug porpose, didn't help)
  end
```

And this is the full Trace

C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'                      C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:352:in`respond_to?' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/wrapper.rb:14:in `wrap' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb:174:in`error_messages_for' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1012:in `error_messages' D:/Workspace/Aptana/UltimateJournal/app/views/nutritions/_form.html.erb:3:in`_run_erb_app47views47nutritions47_form46html46erb_locals_form_object' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:499:in `fields_for' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:282:in`form_for' D:/Workspace/Aptana/UltimateJournal/app/views/nutritions/_form.html.erb:2:in `_run_erb_app47views47nutritions47_form46html46erb_locals_form_object' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in`send' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in`with_template' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in`render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:26:in `benchmark' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:10:in `realtime' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:26:in `benchmark' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in`render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in`render_partial' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in`render' D:/Workspace/Aptana/UltimateJournal/app/views/nutritions/new.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47nutritions47new46html46erb' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in`send' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in`with_template' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in`render_template' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in`_render_with_layout' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in`render_for_file' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:945:in `render_without_benchmark' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in`render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:10:in`realtime' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in`render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in`perform_action_without_filters' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in`perform_action_without_benchmark' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:10:in `realtime' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`ms' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in`perform_action_without_flash' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in`send' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in`process' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in`dispatch' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in`build_middleware_stack' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in`cache' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`synchronize' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in`call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:64:in`process' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in`each' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in`run' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in`new' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in`initialize' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in`run' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111 C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`gem_original_require' C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' script/server:3-e:2:in`load'-e:2

Comment: What is the full error stack ? (including the files and lines number of the failure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks fine, just naming an attribute as "class" does not seem to be a good idea, it's usually pretty much reserved word...

Comment: You are right, i added migrations to the model (class, type => nutri_class, nutri_type).
Do i need to change anything else in my nifty_scaffold ? eg. Change the view, controller, ...?

Because, my nutri_class, nutri_type in the view of :action => "new", automaticly have the text "Nutrition" in them. How come?

Comment: you need to change names of fields in your views, which were generated by scaffold, default values would be probably set in view